# How to round up and return an integer value?

Tags: vb.net, math, built-in

I know about the Math.Round and Math.Ceiling methods, but they return a Double and a Decimal. Does VB.NET have any built-in functions which always round a floating point number up, not down, with a return type of Integer? I know there's CInt, but this can round down if it's below 6.5.

Comment: You can always use `CInt` on what you get from `Round` or `Ceiling`. Also, I believe `CInt`'s rounding behavior is consistent both above and below 6.5 (not that this matters once you've rounded already).

Comment: Just add .5 to it before you round it...

Comment: Are you saying you want to round up even with `6.1`?

Comment: @Asad - So there's no single method that does that?

Comment: Why not write your own.

Comment: @LeoKing I don't think so. It adds like 5 characters to your code, why would it matter? It isn't like this is PHP, where you need to have a global namespace function for everything.

Comment: Please write down your test cases. What you want to achieve, and what existing functions are giving you.

Comment: It doesn't matter tremendously, @Asad, I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it. I'll stick with your method even if it looks a bit  clunky, it doesn't seem worth its own function :). If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I understood you wanted to round `6.1` to `7`.
Just add 1 and truncate.
If it looks awkward, create a method for it.

**Correction:**

Unless the number already is truncated.

**Addendum:**

Note here that doing == with floats is not without problem; you should always have some sort of precision when trying == with floats.
Now when you have decided on this precision - then you can rewrite your code to add 0.999999 (according to precision) and the first add-0.9999-and-truncat works.

Note again that adding 0.9999 is does not really mean you add 0.9999 with our "normal" float.
So if you really want to add 0.9999 you have to work with BND and/or some monetary arithmetics.
Which you "always" should do when calculating money (or any exact decimal stuff)

Comment: But what does that to 7.0?

Comment: @LutzL A better approach is to add 0.5 and round, as someone pointed out in the comments.